# Which sorting superuser use for displaying reputations of users in one page

Tags: discussion, tags, users

I have come across this page https://superuser.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week and most of the elements look like in sorted order, but some elements are not in sorted order.
Is it supposed to be in sorted order? If yes, then what I am missing?
[image]

And, what should be the tag of this post?

Comment: This sort of question belongs on the Meta site, not the main QA site.

Comment: It appears in order for me when I opened the link.

Comment: Hypothesis: a user with weekly reputation gain of 22 received an upvote (+10) just after the sorting was done, just before the site retrieved reputation values in order to display them. A race condition where values are read twice. In vast majority of cases respective values are the same; hardly ever(?) they change in between, still it's possible.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski understood. thanks for explaining. That means they keep those sorting in memory for sometimes without doing instantly sorting. As reputation is changed 5 minutes before I came to the user page.

Answer (score 1):

These users are sorted according to your selections - by their weekly reputation gain, from left to right and then down a line.